# Bootstrap columns pushing elements in other column down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Example code to illustrate my problem looks like:

```
<div class='body'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       Col Left 1 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Col Right 1 ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     Col Left 2
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

This is how this renders, and the markup on the screenshot is what I would like to fix:

[image]

Ultimately, on my application, I would like to have my forms and buttons on one side, and my data display on the other like so:
[image]

What this is doing is pushing everything on the left down and creating a large space between the elements as shown in the example. How do I overcome this and keep the two columns separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. In Bootstrap grid layout, columns must be wrapped by rows. You can re-write your code as below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Col Left 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Col Right 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 border border-info">
      Col Left 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Your layout should now look like the picture below, without space between the columns:

[bootstrap columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDgJ9.png)

Comment: The issue persists. The two left columns continue to separate if there is enough data in "col right 1" to cause them to split. Note my first screenshot.

Comment: Actually, going to go ahead and accept this because row helped me get where I needed to be. Welcome to Stack.

Comment: Thank you @find_all :). Columns in the same row will have the same height as the column with longest content (your Col Right 1) , so column with shorter content (your Col Left 1) will show gap. If you don't want that, then you can nest another set of row-column in Col Right 1 and Col Left 1. That way, the columns height on each side will not be dependent on each other.